# How to get the size of an io.reader object

Tags: go

I would like to get the size of an io.reader to return the length of a picture for a bse64 concerns.

The main problem is to get the size of dec to return a content-length header

Here is my code  :

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "strconv"
    "io"
        base64 "encoding/base64"
    "bytes"

)

func pix(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
    cookie, _ := r.Cookie("csrftoken")
    fmt.Printf(cookie.Value)
}



func img(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
    cookie    :=    http.Cookie{Name: "csrftoken",Value:"abcd",Expires:expiration,HttpOnly: false}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
    img := bytes.NewBufferString("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")
    dec := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, img)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")

// the problem is here i would like to get the size to return the length of the picture  (lend(dec))

    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(dec)))

    io.Copy(w, dec)

}


func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/pix/", pix)
    http.HandleFunc("/img/", img)
    http.HandleFunc("/red/", img)
    http.HandleFunc("/", img)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

regards and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application does not need to set the content length. If the application does not specify the content length, then net/http server uses [chunked encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)  for HTTP/1.1 clients. For HTTP/1.0 clients, the net/http server closes the connection after writing the response. There are some edge cases that are not important for this discussion.  What is important is that the net/http server can write the response without knowing the content length.

Use the following code to write the response:

```
func img(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
  cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "csrftoken",Value:"abcd",Expires:expiration,HttpOnly: false}
  http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)

  img := bytes.NewBufferString("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")
  dec := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, img)
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
  io.Copy(w, dec)
}
```

You can reduce memory allocations by using [strings.NewReader](https://godoc.org/strings#NewReader) instead of bytes.NewBufferString:

```
img := strings.NewReader("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")
```

If the application must avoid chunked responses, then the application must set the Content-Length header.  Decode the image to a buffer, get the length of that buffer and set the header before writing the body:

```
func img(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
  cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "csrftoken",Value:"abcd",Expires:expiration,HttpOnly: false}
  http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)

  p, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("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")
  if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "internal error", 500)
    return
  }
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
  w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(p)))
  w.Write(p)
}
```

Comment: I believe chunked encoding has nothing to do with it. If you send a response without a length, the client will assume the body is done when the connection is closed or when the chunk, like said here, is done. Maybe you are familiar when downloading a large file and the remaining time was unknown. That's because a length was not specified. Specifying a length is an extra security feature letting the client know it has the correct body size.

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier You are describing what a client does when the content length is not specified. I described what the net/http server does when the content length is not specified by the application.

Answer (score 10):

Since `io.Reader` interface doesn't know anything about size or length of underlying data,
there are 2 options:
1- Use buffer and read or copy all data:

```golang
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
nRead, err := io.Copy(buf, dec) 
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(nRead, 10)) //len(dec)
```

Like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    base64 "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func pix(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
    cookie, _ := r.Cookie("csrftoken")
    fmt.Printf(cookie.Value)
}

func img(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
    cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "csrftoken", Value: "abcd", Expires: expiration, HttpOnly: false}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
    img := bytes.NewBufferString("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")
    dec := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, img)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    nRead, err := io.Copy(buf, dec) 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.FormatInt(nRead, 10)) //len(dec)

    io.Copy(w, buf)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/pix/", pix)
    http.HandleFunc("/img/", img)
    http.HandleFunc("/red/", img)
    http.HandleFunc("/", img)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

---

2- Don't set the header size, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    base64 "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func pix(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
    cookie, _ := r.Cookie("csrftoken")
    fmt.Printf(cookie.Value)
}

func img(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
    cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "csrftoken", Value: "abcd", Expires: expiration, HttpOnly: false}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
    img := bytes.NewBufferString("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")
    dec := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, img)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")

    io.Copy(w, dec)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/pix/", pix)
    http.HandleFunc("/img/", img)
    http.HandleFunc("/red/", img)
    http.HandleFunc("/", img)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

Comment: A `Set` on a `Header` after a `Write` has no effect, and will not be sent in the response. @user462794 I believe Go automatically adds a `Content-Length` to HTTP responses too, so it's unnecessary to calculate it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

```
func getSize(stream io.Reader) int {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(stream)
    return buf.Len()
}
```

Comment: that means you have to allocate memory for it...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the size of io.Reader by copying to io.Discard, Discard is a Writer on which all Write calls succeed without doing anything:

```
// r is of type io.Reader
// n is the size    
n, err := io.Copy(io.Discard, r)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `io.Reader` is also `io.Seeker` (for example when you want to serve a file back to the user) you can do the following and avoid caching the file into memory:

```golang
if s, ok := reader.(io.Seeker); ok {
    if size, err := s.Seek(0, io.SeekEnd); err == nil {
        // seek back to the start of file so that it can be served properly
        if _, err = s.Seek(0, io.SeekStart) {
            w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(size))
        }
        // error handeling
    }
    // error handeling
}
// continue serving the file
```